# How to split a .csv without having \n added at the end of the list?

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to split a .csv into a dictionary inside a list but it adds to the string in the last position a following `"\n"`.

The .csv has this form:

```
user;password
```

For example if I code this:

```
accounts = []
file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/users.csv"))

for line in file : 
    data = line.split(";")
    user = {"user": data[0], "pass": data[1]}
    accounts.append(user)
print(accounts)
```

When I print it looks like:

```
[{'user': 'dd', 'pass': '456\n'}]
```

with the \n added at the end.

Comment: Use `data = line.strip().split(";")`

Comment: Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library. You won't have to manually strip new lines then

Answer (score 1):

```
"pass": data[1].strip('\n')
```

will strip newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader) class to handle the delimiter (`;`), the iteration over the rows, and the removal of the newline character.

```
import csv

accounts = []
with open('users.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
  for row in reader:
    username, password = row  
    accounts.append({"user":username, "pass": password})
```

Each `row` will be a list (ex. `['aaa', '123']`) with the newline character already removed. You just need to access each element in the correct order.

Comment: @user11879211 Glad to help :) Here at Stack Overflow, if an answer helped you, we usually [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. See [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)